# What are the performance difference between browsing in Chrome's Regular Window vs Incognito Window?

Tags: google-chrome

Aside from not storing your web browsing history, what are the performance differences between browsing a website in Chrome's Regular Window vs Incognito Window?

Are there any power or performance differences?

Is Regular Chrome browsing better in speed and power compared to Incognito browsing?

Answer (score 4):

Incognito will always be slower than regular chrome.  The main reason for this is that when in icognito mode, the browser doesn't store cache.

This means that each time you visit a page, the css files, javascript, images etc all have to be re-downloaded from the web server, which makes sites generally load a little slower - but is brilliant for web developers like myself who hate chasing an issue for an hour only to realise the browser is using a cached file.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I completely agree with Fazer I will also point out that by default all plugins/Chrome apps are disabled in incognito mode, depending on the number and type of plugins you have installed this will reduce the memory usage of the browser and reduce parsing of the webpage before rendering (e.g. AdBlock), providing a speed boost in the browser it's self.

Comment: good point Dan.  I was focussing on just the browser as I have very few extensions or addons, but what is lost in cache downloads can easily be made up in browser speed.

Comment: It's very dependant on the user, as you say with few extensions this difference is negligible, I have quite a few installed and I notice a fair bit less memory usage in Incognito.